# Linux - touch missing file operand, why?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Unesite argument:$1 "
var=$1

if [[ ! -f "$var" ]]
then
        touch $var
        sleep 1
        echo "Nova datoteka $var je kreirana."
else
        echo "Ova datoteka vec postoji, unesite drugu."
        sleep 1
fi
```

Why do I get "touch missing file operand"

Comment: please don't post pictures of text. I can't read this, select parts of it, let any tools run on it… Instead, simply copy&paste the text, select it, and click on the "code formatting" button labeled `{}` in the question editor.

Comment: so, have you checked what the content of `var` actually is?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide the script with an argument. As a result, both `$1` and `$var` expand to the empty string.

The empty string is certainly not the name of a file that exists, so `touch $var` is executed. Because you didn't *quote* the expansion, it's equivalent to `touch` with no argument at all.

If you *had* quoted `$var`, you'd execute `touch ""`, which would give you a different error message, along the lines of

```
touch: : No such file or directory
```

because again, the empty string is not a legal file name.

Comment: Additional info: it may seem the quotes here just trade one error for another, but [they are important for other reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).